# What is the correct pronunciation of Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, community

I know [how to pronounce Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34980/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-ubuntu) but I don't know how to pronounce Xubuntu (which I'm currently enjoying). Should it be

- **'zoo'-buntu** or
- **'eks'-ubuntu** or
- something else ?

(Similarly 'loo'-buntu or 'el'-ubuntu, 'koo'-buntu or 'kay'-ubuntu?)

Maybe this is just a matter of opinion (unlike for the real preexisting word [ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424/what-does-ubuntu-mean)), but I want to get it right if there is a right way.

Comment: I tend to pronounce it as kʰoobuntu because of the [Chi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_(letter)) (I'm basied by my field of study...) and then Koobuntu, with a non-aspired K. But sometimes, depending whom I am talking to, I use ksoobuntu (without the "e" at the beginning, like in "xylitol", there is no "e" there) and Kayoobuntu. I never use eksubuntu (because there is no "e" there) or zoobuntu (that would be the pronunciation of Zubuntu)

Comment: Here's a guide for all: http://imgur.com/gallery/QrT64rO

Comment: @BharadwajRaju That's a really helpful page :)

Comment: I pronounce it as "gzubuntu" (with the first "gz" sound being like the end of "eggs" rather than as in GNU etc, as if you were saying "eggs ubuntu") but I don't think that is an official pronunciation... just adding it as I seem to be unique in this!

Comment: Since "Ubuntu" is a Bantu word, I like to have some fun and pronounce "Xubuntu" with a click like [the X in Xhosa](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f4/Alveolar_lateral_click.ogg): /ǁubuntu/

Comment: @wjandrea that's my favourite suggestion :-)

Comment: You mean it's not pronounced "Ten Ubuntu"? I've been saying it wrong.

Comment: That's the exact quotation that I had in my mind for months! Thanks @Zanna :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The first one... Zoo-buntu!

That's how it's described [here](http://linux.wikia.com/wiki/Xubuntu):

> **Xubuntu** (Pronounced: /zù'búntú/) is an official Ubuntu-based operating system.

Lubuntu = Loo-buntu

Kubuntu = Koo-buntu, though I always seem to pronounce it as more of a Kuh sound.

Comment: Looks good, thanks a lot; now when I attend a linux-y meetup and am asked 'so what are you running?' I can reply without fear :)

Comment: So, there will never be a Zubuntu variant then.

Comment: @MrLister it'll be confusing if there is, but never say never!

Comment: All I can say as a teacher of English to foreigners is the official pronunciation is confusing for non-native English speakers. Please see some of the other answers for far better alternatives.

Comment: You might be happy to know I actually met an employee of Canonical at an event and she asked me, "Are you using Ubuntu?" and I said, confidently, "I'm using Zoo-buntu" and just to be sure added "Am I saying it right?", and she said "Yeah that's it."

Comment: @Zanna good times. I tend to have too great a sense of humour bias towards the absurd, and in your position would've done an X symbol with my arms, like Xzibit did in some early 2000s rap video. This is why I'm not allowed to go to events... at least not without a chaperone.

Answer (score 13):

Pragmatic answer: don't forget that these distros are used by people whose native language isn't English... any pronunciation which is not ambiguous/misleading for your audience is fine. Your audience should be able to infer the spelling from your pronunciation. Pronounce "Zoo-buntu" in front of French people and they will google for Zubuntu after the meeting...

Comment: Welcome to the community! You seem skeptic writing this answer, though.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. Actually tested this at lunch, with people that know about Linux but aren't familiar with the distros in general and even less so with the Ubuntu variants. The only person who would consider that "zooboontoo" could start with an X was the native English speaker, and that was after trying with a "Z".  In how many languages is "X" pronounced like "Z" at the beginning of words? And what percentage of Linux users do they cover?

Comment: Yes, I would never have thought of "zoo-boon-too" as the spelling of Xubuntu. I grew up with German, and learned French and English later.

Comment: @user258532 I thought it was "ksubundu" ("nt" in Greek is pronounced as "d" or "nd", I thought that "eksubundu" minus the "e" to make it one work was "ksubundu" before realizing it was "zubundu").

Comment: +1 for the same would occur with a Portuguese speaking audicence, which would probably pronounce what would sound *shoo*boontoo in English.

Comment: Actually it makes most sense to pronounce it so that everyone will understand. Thanks "Zenoid".

Answer (score 10):

Concerning Xubuntu, I go for **ksoo-buntu**...

My suggestion for Kubuntu would be **Q-buntu**. I pronounce Lubuntu as **loo-buntu** (with a short oo, unlike the toilet).

Comment: It's not "short oo", it's something like "u (oo)" I think.

Answer (score 8):

In contrast to the other answer, I call them by the letter then Ubuntu, so based on your examples

'eks'-ubuntu

'el'-ubuntu

'kay'-ubuntu

This is the correct way to pronounce them IMO because the names are based on the desktops they use, they are

'eks' FCE

'el' XDE

'kay' DE

Respectively, people can call them what ever they like but looking at where the names come from, this seems the correct way.

Comment: +1 for good logic, even if other sources disagree, I will be better prepared to argue it out in the pub...

Comment: To counter my own position on this, I guess you could argue that 'eks'-ubuntu should by hyphenated ie X-Ubuntu, with out that it is all one word and would be zoo-buntu, I need to stop thinking about this :/

Comment: That's what I thought too, since it's not hyphenated it should be fused. Sorry for messing with your head haha

Comment: Also on there website the U in Ubuntu is not capitalized, it is Xubuntu not XUbuntu, I guess this all so backs up zoo-buntu as the correct pronunciation. I am still going to use eks-ubuntu though, just because I think it sounds better :)

Comment: @ChrisDown I have never heard that before but it is wrong https://www.google.co.uk/?client=ubuntu#channel=fs&q=xfce+definition&gfe_rd=cr It is an acronym for `XForms Common Environment`

Comment: Applying “good logic” is a bit hopeless though, if the topic is software names.  Gnome is pronounced /nəʊm/ though its name derives from GTK which is the acronym for Gimp ToolKit, where Gimp is in turn short for GNU Image Manipulation Program, which I won't get started about lest I get trapped in an infinite loop...

Answer (score 5):

## Zu-buntu

### Information

> Note: On [1], please "Disable SSL Protection" in order to see poll results more clearly. Alternatively, click [here](//ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=441725)[1].

From [[1]](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=441725) (Ubuntu Forums) (SSL) (emphasis mine):

> [This is an active poll, so I cannot do exact quoting]
>
> [Note that even if the last answer is from 2007, these can change any time]
>
> **201 voters**
>
> - shoo-BOON-too: **15** (**7.46%**)
> - ksoo-BOON-too: **51** (**25.37%**)
> - **ECKS-oo-BOON-too: 76** (**37.81%**)
> - shuh-BUN-too: **9** (**4.48%**)
> - KSYOO-boon-too: **3** (**1.49%**)
> - ksuh-boon-TOO: **20** (**9.95%**)
>
> [Stupid ones]
>
> - tsongas-HOO: **0** (**0%**)
> - SKOO-bee-DOO: **7** (**3.48%**)
> - SPORK-for-TOO: **3** (**1.49%**)
> - BOO-tros-BOO-tros-GAH-lee: **17** (**8.46%**)

This confirms "exu-buntu" is correct.

From [[2]](//linux.wikia.com/wiki/Xubuntu) (Wikia:Linux) (emphasis mine):

> Xubuntu (Pronounced: **/zù'búntú/**) is an official Ubuntu-based operating system.

This confirms "zu-buntu" is correct.

From [[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu) (English Wikipedia) (SSL) (emphasis mine) ("special" links removed):

> Xubuntu (**/zuːˈbuːntuː/ *zoo-BOON-too***) is a [Canonical Ltd.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Ltd.)–recognized, community-maintained derivative of the [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)) [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system).

This, again, confirms that "zu-buntu" is correct.

### Results

From these sources, we can conclude that:

- "exu-buntu" has got **1 vote**
- "zu-buntu" has got **2 votes—Winner**