# How to correctly pronounce Xenial Xerus?

Tags: 16.04

When referring to the latest Ubuntu 16.04 to friends, I often struggle about the pronunciation of "Xenial Xerus".

**Is there a universal pronunciation form? If so, which is? If not, how to determine the pronunciation in my native non-English language?**

Note: I am aware of a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779376/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-xubuntu) about Xubuntu. However, there are quite a [few differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel) between *u*  and *e* which *might* alter the pronunciation (like in "gel" and "gun").

Comment: I pronounce it "sixteen point four".

Comment: @Mark isn't it 16.04, though? I say  "sixteen oh four."

Comment: @Zacharee1: The four is the fourth month of the year.  Ubuntu version numbers will never have an ambiguity between 16.4 and 16.04.  Also, even though you might write a date of April fool's day as 16.04.01, you might still say "sixteen / four / one".  So the "sixteen point four" pronunciation takes advantage of the knowledge / understanding that Ubuntu version numbers are date-based.  If not for this, you absolutely should pronounce the zeros in version numbers.

Comment: @Mark just like people pronounce "OS [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals)" as "OS Ten"! :)

Comment: jenial jerux i say. also sixteen point zero four

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**They are both dictionary words**

[xenial](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/xenial?s=t) [xerus](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/xerus?s=t) (sound clips included here)

### zee-nee-ul zeer-us

or in [IPA](https://www.englishclub.com/images/pronunciation/Phonemic-Chart.jpg)

### **/ˈzi:nɪəlˈzɪərəs/**

Comment: Wow, that is a totally different pronunciation from the one I was expecting. What about in other languages? Do you accommodate?

Comment: I'm curious to know how else you might pronounce it other than this? It's quite well known I thought that an X is pronounced like a Z, like in Xenophobic, for instance, it's just Zenophobic.

Comment: @luchonacho you can pronounce it however you like as far as I'm concerned, but it is made up of two preexisting English words and this is the canonical (and Canonical, presumably) pronunciation of them.

Comment: @i-CONICA. Indeed, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X#English) it says that **most** (but not all) of words starting with _X_ are pronounced as _Z_. My original thinking was that those two words were not of English origin, and I see from Zanna's links that they come from the Greek. Maybe a [Greek pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_(letter)) of _X_ was possible.

Comment: @Zanna, naturally, I can pronounce is as I like it (freedom as in free speech), but I wonder if there is a guidance in using Ubuntu names in other languages. Actually, Ubuntu as pronounced in English ("oo-boon-too”) **is not** how it is pronounced in Spanish (my native language).

Comment: @luchonacho But the canonical pronunciation of ubuntu is not an "English" pronunciation because it is not an English word. Language rules are descriptive rather than prescriptive in my opinion, but I repeat myself, these are English words and this is how to pronounce them. With time, your own language may acquire these words and evolve their pronunciation, but this is the original language so should be considered standard

Comment: @luchonacho No “native” English words (whatever *that* means, for a language where over 60% of vocabulary can be traced to Latin or Greek) start with an *x*; almost all of them come from Greek. English speakers have a very difficult time starting a word with a *ks* sound for whatever reason, as one would in the original Greek for these words, so the *z* sound is used instead.

Comment: Convinced! :) Good point about English language...

Comment: @luchonacho It’s also worth noting that in cases like phonetic radio alphabets (where words starting with a letter are used to relay that letter to reduce miscommunication), the most common choice for X is *x-ray*, which is pronounced *eks ray* —the preceding *e* sound makes it pronounceable for English speakers, while avoiding a *z* sound that might be confused for the actual letter Z. Which reminds me of another interesting example: the name *Xavier* is pronounced either *zavier* or *eksavier*, but never *ksavier*, by English speakers.

Comment: @luchonacho Since Xenial Xerus is an English name, it should be pronounced with the English pronunciation even when talking in other languages.

Answer (score 6):

It follows closely the Xubuntu pronunciation that you've referenced.

**[Zee-ni-al](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/xenial) [Zee-rus](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/xerus)**

Would be the best way to describe it.

Answer (score 4):

The same as it sounds at Google Translate when the English language selected. Click on the speaker icon at the bottom of the input text box to listen to it pronounced. It sounds like **zee**-nee-al **zee**-rus with the accent on the first syllable in both words.