# How do I pronounce Mate

Tags: mate

I always wondered how do I pronounce Mate in 'Ubuntu Mate'.

I am listening to a podcast and one of the two people always says **'mahteh'**. It sounds very weird to me, because I pronounce it **'mate'** like the english word for friend.

There is also [ubuntu-mate.org](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/how-to-pronounce-mate/), which says it is pronounced **'mah-tay'** and that is the only right pronunciation.

---

How would you pronounce it? Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: IMHO you should join the discussion on the linked page, the question might be marked as opinion-based here.

Comment: I think you answered your own question here, the developers know how to pronounce the name of there own product. Your faulty assumption here is that the word is English, you can see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATE_(software) it is a Spanish word and should be pronounced as such..

Comment: I've always looked at it as `mah-tay`.  When I first read your question titled that is how I heard it in my mind.  When I saw it years ago I looked up the pronunciation... [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATE_(software)) and  [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rqt1Q_lL5M.)

Comment: totally agree with @MarkKirby - you answered your own question and there's nothing to say

Comment: There is a similar question to Xubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/779376/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-xubuntu/779383 I hope it is not getting closed because I don't think it is an opinion-based question. @MarkKirby Please add your comment as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: I agree with @Anwar the question was answered by the devs already and as I am not a dev, I would just be pointing people to the very video you mentioned it the question, as that is the explanation. Perhaps opinion is not the best reason to closed but, as you answered your own question, all we can give is our opinion. The only way I see this as answerable is if one of the devs shows up, proves who they are and chooses to answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If developers themselves specify the pronunciation, no one is more authorized to say otherwise. There cannot be other options after that.

So, it is what you already gave in the question. "mah-tay". As devs wrote here

https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/how-to-pronounce-mate/

Comment: Oddly enough, la piece de resistance from that link - the video containing the pronunciation of the word "Mate"- was deleted because it was supposedly breaking YouTube's rules!!! o.O

Comment: Really!! I haven't watched the video! odd indeed